# Why is astype(int) not changing a numpy array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to convert float values of a column in a 3D array:

```
for i in range(timeseries_resampled.shape[0]):
    timeseries_resampled[i, :, 9] = (np.rint(timeseries_resampled[i, :, 9])).astype(int)
    print(timeseries_resampled[i, :, 9].dtype) # float64
    print(timeseries_resampled[i, :, 9].astype(int).dtype) # int64
```

Why is the first assignment of the `for`loop not working. I am not quite sure why it does not work. I also tried to set `copy=False` but nothing is working.

Here is an example:

```
a = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    a[i, :, 3] = a[i, :, 3].astype(int)
    print(a[i, :, 3])
    print(a[i, :, 3].astype(int))
```

with output

```
[0. 0. 0.]
[0 0 0]
[0. 0. 0.]
[0 0 0]
```

so `a[i, :, 3]` contains only float values whereas `a[i, :, 3].astype(int)` contains only int values. So why is the assignment

```
a[i, :, 3] = a[i, :, 3].astype(int)
```

not working? I expected `a[i, :, 3]` to contain only int values now.

Comment: It would make it easier for people to reproduce your problem and help to solve it if you could provide a minimal reproduceable example rather than a snippet of your code.

Comment: @FiddleStix I will provide an example in a moment.

Comment: @FiddleStix I provided the example now

Answer (score 1):

`dtype` is a property of the array itself, not the values being added to the array. `timeseries_resampled` has a `dtype` of `float64`, so whatever values you put in the array are converted from whatever type they may have to `float64` on assignment.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my example and tell me how to get my desired result, if that is possible?

Comment: You have to create a new array, or change the type of the array itself. You can't just stick values of type `int` into an array of `float`s. The entire point of a Numpy array is to have a predetermined datatype of the elements so that the data can be stored efficiently.